# Angular2 (vaadin angular2-polymer): How to reference images

Tags: angular, webpack, vaadin, polymer-1.0

I have a angular2 / webpack project which uses polymer elements. I'm using the following element:

```
<paper-card image="img/home.jpg">
```

in my home component:

- Home

  - img

    - home.jpg
  - home.component.ts

I have the following webpack config:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

output: {
    path: './public/js/app',
    publicPath: "/js/app/",
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
},
entry: {
    'app': './assets/app/main.polymer.ts'
},

resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
},

module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loaders: [
                'awesome-typescript-loader',
                'angular2-template-loader',
                'angular2-router-loader'
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'html'
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: 'raw'
        }
    ]
},

plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
        // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
        /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
        './src' // location of your src
    )
]
};
```

The app gets loaded correctly & I have angular / polymer components beeing displayed. So the base is set up correctly. But when I look at the paper-card element, then I do not see the image in it. I also see in the dev tools that the image is never served.

What do I need to change, so that the image is displayed correctly? Probably a webpack config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely something wrong with our project setup, either the folder structure is wrong, or something is missing it the webpack config.

As far as I can see, your webpack config does not have any loader targeted at image files. I guess, this is what happens now:

- Webpack does not know how to process your image, and therefore it does not process it.
- The image url comes to browser unmodified.
- Then the browser requests the image from the output public path, but it is not there, as it stays near the component file in the app source path.

Basically, you have two options:

- Continue without webpack processing for images. You can move your image in the public folder directly, so it is served directly from there, its url is permanent, and webpack does not touch the image file and does not modify the url.
- Alternatively, you can keep your image in the app source path, near the component file. This requires to extend the webpack config and a loader for image files, for example, using the `file-loader`:

  ```
  loaders: [
    /* ... */
    {
      test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)/i,
      loader: 'file'
    }
  ]
  ```

  This way, webpack loads the image, then copies (“emits”) it to the output folder, and then modifies the path referencing this image with the output file path.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestions @anton-platonov. I've included the loader and installed the npm package "file-loader". But still it does not get served. 
However, when I copy the img directory in public/img, then it works like a charm. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Well, the relative parts should work, in general. I guess, the next step is to ensure that your component template itself is processed by webpack loaders.

Maybe try to extract the component HTML template to a separate file, and reference it using `templateUrl`? This way, I believe, `html-loader` should pick and process the template, invoking the `file-loader` for the image url.

Comment: Thanks again for helping me - you really rock! I already extracted it in a separate file and call the templateURL like: `templateUrl: './home.component.html',`

Are you absolutely sure that it has nothing to do with vaadin? Because when I use `<img src="img/home.jpg">` then everything works perfect.

Comment: Oh, right, there is one more step to go. Thanks for trying `<img src="img/home.jpg">`. The reason is that, unlike the `<img src>`, `<paper-card image="img/home.jpg">` is not a standard HTML syntax, therefore, `html-loader` is not aware of this way of loading content out of the box. We should probably extend the webpack config and tell the `html-loader` to process the `image` attribute of `paper-card` as well. Please add the `htmlLoader: { attrs: [ 'img:src', 'paper-card:image' ] }` key to you webpack config. See also: https://github.com/webpack/html-loader#advanced-options

Comment: @AntonPlatonov Regarding the `html-loader`, is that also how `angular2-polymer` handles attributes on Polymer elements?

Comment: @tony19 sorry, I don’t quite understand your question. In general, the `angular2-polymer` library does not affect the way attributes work on Polymer elements.

Answer (score 2):

Just needed to add in the webpack config:

```
    plugins: [
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        // test: /\.xxx$/, // may apply this only for some modules
        options: {
            htmlLoader: {
                attrs: ['paper-card:image']
            }
        }
    })
]
```